# Pandas - create column based on column names referenced in another column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, mapping, slice

I have tried mutliple things (maps, filters, joins), but nothing seems to work.
What I am trying to do is best described by the following table: (I need to get the "required" column)

```
    colA    colB    colC    ref     required
1   a1        b1    c1      colA     a1
2   a2        b2    c2      colA     a2
3   a3        b3    c3      colB     b3
4   a4        b4    c4      colB     b4
5   a5        b5    c5      colC     c5
6   a6        b6    c6      colC     c6
```

The above is just an example - in the real example I have >50 columns, so doing conditions is not going to work...

Any suggestions how to do this?

Comment: How do do what? Can you elaborate on which columns you start with and which columns you need to create, and how you create them?

Comment: Sorry - just added it. I need to get the "required" column

Answer (score 4):

If I understand your issue correctly, the following `apply` will do the trick:

```
# Starting DataFrame:
>>> df
  colA colB colC   ref
1   a1   b1   c1  colA
2   a2   b2   c2  colA
3   a3   b3   c3  colB
4   a4   b4   c4  colB
5   a5   b5   c5  colC
6   a6   b6   c6  colC

df['required'] = df.apply(lambda x: x.loc[x.ref], axis=1)

# Final DataFrame:
>>> df
  colA colB colC   ref required
1   a1   b1   c1  colA       a1
2   a2   b2   c2  colA       a2
3   a3   b3   c3  colB       b3
4   a4   b4   c4  colB       b4
5   a5   b5   c5  colC       c5
6   a6   b6   c6  colC       c6
```

Answer (score 3):

I'd use [lookup method](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.lookup.html):

```
In [85]: df['required'] = df.lookup(df.index, df.ref)

In [86]: df
Out[86]:
  colA colB colC   ref required
1   a1   b1   c1  colA       a1
2   a2   b2   c2  colA       a2
3   a3   b3   c3  colB       b3
4   a4   b4   c4  colB       b4
5   a5   b5   c5  colC       c5
6   a6   b6   c6  colC       c6
```